# Cartalyst Sentinel with Laravel Socialite conflict

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-socialite, cartalyst-sentinel

I have a laravel app where I have integrated Cartalyst Sentinel and Laravel Socialite. Before integrating Laravel Socialite, the authentication worked perfectly. After integrating Socialite, first I had an `InvalidStateException` error on `AbstractProvider.php` line 200 when I call `Socialite::driver('facebook')->user();`

The following block is activated

```
if ($this->hasInvalidState()) {
        throw new InvalidStateException;
}
```

If I comment out the exception, I can login with facebook, however Sentinel does not recognized it as logged in. However when I check the users table on the database, the last_login timestamp is updated. Also when I try the normal authentication, a `TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 67` appears. The `{{csrf_field()}}` is included inside the form, and when I remove the middleware from `Kernel.php` happens the same thing as with Laravel Socialite.

**Important**

The response is the correct eloquent user object, however when I do the check in the blade view, the check does not pass.

Any help is greatly appreciated